# SimplePing unexpected packet

Tags: swift, networking, ping

I'm using Apple's [SimplePing](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/SimplePing/Introduction/Intro.html) to ping many different addresses.

However, if I create & start more than 1 `SimplePing` instance at a time, I get unexpected packets.

Here is what I'm currently doing:

```
class Test: NSObject, SimplePingDelegate {
    var simplePing: SimplePing
    init(hostName: String) {
        simplePing = SimplePing(hostName: hostName)
        super.init()
        simplePing.delegate = self
        simplePing.start()
    }
    func simplePing(_ pinger: SimplePing, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Failed")
    }
    func simplePing(_ pinger: SimplePing, didStartWithAddress address: Data) {
        print("started")
        simplePing.send(with: nil)
    }
    func simplePing(_ pinger: SimplePing, didReceiveUnexpectedPacket packet: Data) {
        print("Received unexpected")
    }
    func simplePing(_ pinger: SimplePing, didSendPacket packet: Data, sequenceNumber: UInt16) {
        print("Sent packet")
    }
    func simplePing(_ pinger: SimplePing, didReceivePingResponsePacket packet: Data, sequenceNumber: UInt16) {
        print("Received response")
    }
    func simplePing(_ pinger: SimplePing, didFailToSendPacket packet: Data, sequenceNumber: UInt16, error: Error) {
        print("failed to send packet")
    }
}
```

If I do this:

```
// Below are properties
var test: Test!
var test2: Test!

test = Test(hostName: "www.amazon.com")
test2 = Test(hostName: "www.google.com")
```

I get a bunch of unexpected packets. I tried putting them in different `DispatchQueue`'s and even different `Thread`'s, but it seems to still be receiving unexpected packets.

Is there any  way to fix this? Or, does it even matter that I'm receiving unexpected packets? Should I just ignore the unexpected packets?